# How to do plus operation in SUM formula?

Tags: excel

I have this excel sheet that need to be adjusted. I have this STOCK Quantity column (STOCK Qty) and I need it's column to be linked to the AZ column on sheet1. And it just not linked directly, but i need to plus 9 to get it linked to the exact column.

Here to explain it further. First i need to add this formula into the "STOCK Qty" column D2 : **=SUM(Sheet1!AZ1)** :

[image]

But then on the column after that, say column D3, D4 and so on, i need to add 9 to each column. So column D3 will have the formula of **=SUM(Sheet1!AZ10)** and D4 will have the formula of **=SUM(Sheet1!AZ19)** and so on :

[image]

So, i hope that you could understand my question. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `INDEX` function with `ROWS` to increment by 9 each row - try this formula in D2 copied down

`=INDEX(Sheet1!AZ:AZ,9*(ROWS(D$2:D2)-1)+1)`

Note you probably don't need `SUM`, either with this formula or yours because its only a single value

Comment: Sometimes I wonder... where do you suddenly appear from... :p Had to discard my answer `=SUM(INDIRECT("Sheet1!AZ" &(9*(ROWS(D$2:D2)-1)+1)))`

Comment: Hi barry, i have tried to copy ur formula into the column D2, but excel gave me an error. this is the file : https://app.box.com/s/sxm816tuzlyzl563fxmb

Comment: I used the formula OK in your sheet - my regional settings require commas between arguments, you may need semi-colons, try this version `=INDEX(Sheet1!AZ:AZ;9*(ROWS(D$2:D2)-1)+1)`

Answer (score 1):

I will use the offset function, instead

```
=SUM(OFFSET(Sheet1!$AZ$1,(ROW()-2)*9,0))
```

In addition, if you are not summing anything, just

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$AZ$1,(ROW()-2)*9,0)
```